# TimeZoneInfo.DisplayName returns incorect value [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, timezone

well, it's pretty strange but I've created simple UWP project and add simple line into the code:

```
IEnumerable<string> TimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Select(_ => _.DisplayName);
```

When I execute program I'm getting expected result:

- (UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11",
- (UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands",
- (UTC-10:00) Hawaii",
- (UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands",
- ...

But if I'll set flag **"Compile with .Net Native tool chain"**, I will get:

- UTC-11
- Aleutian Standard Time
- Hawaiian Standard Time
- Marquesas Standard Time
- ...

Is it possible somehow to get expected behaviour with **"Compile with .Net Native tool chain"**?

Comment: I've resolved it in next way. In .Net enumerate all values and save them into Dictionary. And in UWP just taken appropriate value from Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue.

It seems that when enabling the .Net Native tool chain, the DisplayName property will return the same value as the StandardName property. I have logged this issue in our system.

As a workaround you can combine the UTC Offset value with the StandardName as following:

```
        var TimeZoneList=TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        foreach(var i in TimeZoneList)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = i.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);

            if (ts.ToString().Contains("-"))
            {
                string s = "(UTC" + ts.ToString() + ")" + i.StandardName;

            }
            else
            {
                string s = "(UTC+" + ts.ToString() + ")" + i.StandardName;

            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly with this fix I wouldn't get expected result. Instead of:
(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11,
(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands,
(UTC-10:00) Hawaii .... Will be  (UTC-11:00) UTC-11, (UTC-10:00)Aleutian Standard Time ...